# How to install Linux without Internet, and Upgrade it?

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, repository

For example, I have an .iso file for Ubuntu.

Normal after an installation it's good to do an "apt-get update" and "apt-get upgrade" to actualize the apps and system.

I did for example, a copy of the sofwarelist of an upgraded-actual system, in a file e.g. UpdateList.sh.
Then executed it to download the packets from the list to a removable drive.
And shift it to a new installed operating system without internet, to install the packets of the list.

Maybe it's possible to pack the new packets into an iso file or to access e.g. an usb-storage with the respective packets during installation.

How it's possible to do an update/upgrade without internet during installation or after installation of an operating system (linux) ?

Answer (score 1):

i beleived you would need to

1. Download the packages (or iso)
2. Copy them to a location on your linux system (or mount iso)
3. make a custom repository
4. apt-get update

Theres a related question in askubuntu:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/648963/how-to-create-custom-repository-on-ubuntu-14-04